# beforeModel not triggered on all transitions?

Tags: ember.js

I need  a systematic redirection to a login page when user is not authenticated. For that purpose, `beforeModel` in the application route seemed to be the best option, but it seems that `beforeModel` is **not** triggered for all transitions, unlike `willTransition`, which is always called, but when the route is exited, not entered...

For instance, `beforeModel` is not called when changing the URL manually.

I've read this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) which explains that `willTransition` is always called, which I confirm, but it doesn't explain if `beforeModel` should always be called or not, and in which conditions.

I'm using Ember 1.2.0 beta 3 but I have the same problem with 1.1.2 and login redirection is actually handled by [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) (my issue on the repo: [#27](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/27)).

Could someone explain when should `beforeModel` be called ?

**Note** : I've asked the [same question on Ember Discuss](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/beforemodel-not-triggered-on-all-transitions/3250) but had no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 1.1.0-beta.4 and beforeModel works fine. beforeModel should be called in any case like URL change or a transition with a model (e.g. via link-to). The model hook is skipper if we use link-to or transition from a controller.

To get more info and help with debugging set LOG_TRANSITIONS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```